# tracking multiple object locations

Tags: drone

I have a requirement in which I want to track 10+ robots in a field (or hanger), the robots are small.

My first thought would be to use a drone to act as a collector, monitoring the position of each robot, but what should I use to track and measure positions. I need to know where each robot is down to a 1 inch accuracy.

Alternatively could I use some kind of 10 DOF device on each robot to calculate it's actual position from a starting point?

I could also have some kind of post system to act as beacons - but no more than 6-8 in a 80m x 20m area.

Be grateful for any pointers.

thanks

Comment: Is there a GPS reception over the field?

Comment: Yes GPS reception could be acceptable

Comment: So make the robots to read their locations from GPS and transmit it to your tracker.

Comment: what kind of robot? If it runs on wheels you can count revolutions of each wheel and calculate coordinates from a starting point. Accuracy can be made quite good.

Comment: Would like to transfer to animals when proven with robots so wheels are out I'm afraid